# Aborted connection to db. Got an error reading communication packets

Tags: laravel, database-connection, google-cloud-sql

Inside the logs on Google Cloud SQL instance we are getting an error when some request are issued to database. We use Laravel 5.8 and Second generation MySQL instance.

Increasing `max_allowed_packet` didn't help.

`Aborted connection 436828 to db: 'xxx' user: 'xxx' host: cloudsqlproxy~xx.xx.xx.xx' (Got an error reading communication packets)`

Answer (score -4):

In general, the `"Aborted connection nnnn to db:"` message is triggered when an [existing connection is terminated improperly](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/diagnose-issues#aborted-connection). Mostly aborted connections happen because of unclean closure of connection or networking problem between the server and the client as well as other reasons stated [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/communication-errors.html).

To mitigate the problem I would suggest you to follow the [best practices for managing Cloud SQL connections](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/manage-connections) empathizing the [Connection pool](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/manage-connections#pools) and [Opening and closing connections](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/manage-connections#opening_and_closing_connections) sections.